# Passing application context to JSR 303 ConstraintValidator

Tags: bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Some of the JSR-3validation I want to do is context sensitive.

For example, my web application has a "year" context for each request.  When persisting a new bean, I want to be able to constrain the year property to be within year of the current request context.

```
 @InCurrentContextYear
 private LocalDate activationDate;
```

The current year is contained in a request object that I want to pass (in some way) into the constraint validator.   For example:

```
public class InCurrentContextYearValidator 
                  implements ConstraintValidator<InCurrentContextYear, LocalDate>{

    @Override
    public void initialize(InCurrentContextYear constraintAnnotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(
                          LocalDate value, 
                          ConstraintValidatorContext context,
                          Request request) {

        return DateUtil.isInRequestYear(value, request)
    }
}
```

Now I could do this with thread-local storage, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

I do recognize that this is getting somewhat outside the domain of "bean validation" but it seems like using annotations for such things is a defensible approach.   Annotations allow me to keep my beans as POJOs, and service as a nice way to document the rules of the properties.
So why should I need to have an entirely separate mechanism to do essentially the same thing as bean validation?

Comment: Are you using any kind of dependency injection container such as CDI or Spring? If so, you can inject such as a request context into your constraint validator objects.

Comment: Thanks.  But no, we're not using any kind of DI.